# Second level cache in Hibernate 3.2.0 final

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, noclassdeffounderror, second-level-cache

I have been facing problem in using second level cache. following are the required source you need to find out what the problem is.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- a SessionFactory instance -->
    <session-factory>

            <!-- User  / Password -->
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password"></property>

            <!-- Database / Dialect Settings -->
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_001</property>   
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <!-- Second Level Cache -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>               


            <!-- mapping files -->
            <mapping class="com.example.bean.Employee"/>
    </session-factory>
```

Employee Persistance Class

```
    @Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="registration_date")
    private String registrationDate;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }
    public void setRegistrationDate(String registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
}
```

stacktrace

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger    (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory   [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
at          org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:402)
at    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1383)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
at com.example.dao.HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:11)
at com.example.control.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:397)
... 7 more
```

Couldn't create session factory

Comment: Main cause of the error is `ClassNotFoundException:     
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`. Have u included library required for EHCache support ?

Comment: Also, if you're starting a new project, why are you using version 3.2, which is completely obsolete? Start with the lastest version. And use annotations to define your mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a maven based project, add below dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```